# How do I solve to get vector from a dot product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, products

Sorry if this question is quite elementary, I'm not very good at linear algebra. If the dot product of two vectors $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}=c$ then how do I solve for $\mathbf{a}$? I thought I could work it out by turning it into regular algebra ($c = a_1b_1+a_2b_2\ldots$). But after this step I'm stuck already. Please explain the answer if possible.

Comment: You can't since there is no unique solution. If $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}=c$ is a solution, then $(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{n})\cdot\mathbf{b}=c$ is also a solution for any $\mathbf{n}$ normal to $\mathbf{b}$ i.e. $\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{b} = 0\,$.

Comment: You cannot solve for $a$ given just $b$ and $c$

Comment: In fact the equation you derived already suggests this: you have many real unknowns $a_1,a_2,\dots$ but only one equation, so there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @dxiv can you explain that further? I'd like to be able to spot when there isn't a solution in the future (I'm bad at maths). What do you mean by "unique solution" and "n normal to b" etc.?

Comment: @Jonathan `when there isn't a solution` Only case with *no* solution is when $\mathbf{b}=0$ and $c \ne 0$. In all other cases there will be infinitely many solutions. `n normal to b` That's the same as saying that $\mathbf{n}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are orthogonal, or perpendicular, or that $\mathbf{n} \cdot \mathbf{b}=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty clear that there are infinitely many solutions $\mathbf a$, which means that we can't "solve for $\mathbf a$".

Let's look at an example in the $2$-D case: take $\mathbf b = (2,3)$, and consider
$$
\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b = 2 \implies 2a_1 + 3a_2 = 2
$$
Notice that this equation is solvable for **any** value of $a_2$, since we have
$$
2a_1 = 2 - 3a_2 \implies a_1 = 1 - \frac 32 a_2
$$
Which is to say we can consider $a_2$ to be a *free variable*. So, for example, $\mathbf a = (1,0),(- \frac 12, 1),(-2,2),(-5,4)$ are **all** solutions to this equation.

Comment: Is there no way to isolate a vector like **a** from a dot product equation then? The solutions you gave are all on the line $$y=-\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{2}{3}$$ so even though many vectors of varying magnitudes could create **a** I imagine it would always be on the same line. I guess what I'm saying is that the normalized form of vector **a** (and its inverse, even if we can't say which is which) seems like it should always be solvable even if there are infinite solutions within that. ie. Can we find the line that contains **a** if we know 2 and **b**, even if we can't find **a** itself?

Comment: @Brian What do you mean by the "normalized form of vector $\mathbf a$"? What do you mean by the "inverse" of a vector? It is true that in 2 dimensions, we have a "line" of solutions. In general, the version of this equation in $n$ dimensions will have an $(n-1)$-dimensional space of solutions, assuming $\mathbf b \neq \mathbf 0$

Comment: @BrianHandy But yes, given a vector $\mathbf b$, it is easy to characterize the space of all solutions $\mathbf a$